# Prestashop: how to write a non-hardcoded url to a category?

Tags: url, smarty, prestashop

I'm developing a Prestashop-based website locally.
I'm configuring the "slider" module (homepage image slideshow), and it is asking me a URL for each picture. I would like each picture to redirect me to the related category page when clicked on.
However, how to write that URL? Maybe I could write
     `http://localhost/category.php?id_category=5`
... but it won't work when my website will be online.
How to avoid hardcoded url? By using Smarty tag "{$base_dir}"?
I tried several ways... unsuccessfully.
Can you please help?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring the core "homeslider" module do the following:

Open homeslider.tpl from modules/homeslider
replace:

```
{$slide.url|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
```

with:

```
{$base_dir}{$slide.url|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
```

and at the module configuration page for the url instead of:

```
http://localhost/category.php?id_category=5
```

add:

```
category.php?id_category=5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot PrestaShop-Developer.com. It works like a charm!